# Angular 16 and Typescript 5.0 stage 3 decorators don't work as expected

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript-decorator, angular-decorator

I'm managing an Angular component lib in my company (just like Angular Material) and am currently migrating to Angular 16 and Typescript 5. One of the new features are the decorators no longer being experimental (TS 5). I.e., removing this line in the `tsconfig.json`:

```
"experimentalDecorators": true,
```

Also see https://github.com/tc39/proposal-decorators

Also see https://medium.com/@islizeqiang/a-quick-guide-to-typescript-5-0-decorators-d06cabe09e8c

One of the decorators is to manage class fields inside of the local or session storage. The implementation is quite reduced for this question and basically only considers `string`s as values.

```
export function MyStorage(name: string) {

    // we will see this log entry on application
    // startup for every usage of the decorators
    console.log('factory method called');

    // if the function has a proper signature, the compiler
    // will complain for a reason I don't understand, but
    // ...
    return function (...args: unknown[]) {
        // ...it works with a type guard like this
        if (args != null && args.length === 2 && isClassFieldDecoratorContext(args[1])) {
            const context: ClassFieldDecoratorContext = args[1] as ClassFieldDecoratorContext;

            context.addInitializer(function (this: unknown) {
                Object.defineProperty(this, context.name, {
                    set(newValue) {
                        // With the usage below we will see the log entry
                        // 'set someValue to undefined with type undefined'
                        // whenever a `SomeComponent` is being created
                        console.log(`set ${String(context.name)} to ${newValue} with type ${typeof newValue}`);
                        if (newValue == null) {
                            sessionStorage.removeItem(name);
                        } else {
                            sessionStorage.setItem(name, newValue);
                        }
                    },
                    get() {
                        const result = sessionStorage.getItem(name);
                        console.log(`return ${String(context.name)} as ${result} with type ${typeof result}`);
                        return result;
                    },
                });
            });
        }
    };
}

function isClassFieldDecoratorContext(arg: unknown): arg is ClassFieldDecoratorContext {
    return arg != null && typeof arg === 'object' && (arg as ClassFieldDecoratorContext).kind === 'field';
}
```

Usage looks like this:

```
@Component({
    ...
})
export class SomeComponent {

    @MyStorage('some-session-storage-value')
    public someValue!: string;

}
```

So far so normal, but what bugs me: The factory method is only called once, so not on `SomeComponent`s creation (if, for instance, the user browses different Angular routes back and forth and `SomeComponent` is being created and destroyed). How ever, as decorators live outside of Angular life cycles this may be perfectly fine. The problem basically breaks down to the fact, that whenever `SomeComponent` is being created the setter is called with `undefined` as `newValue` (which then will remove the value from the session storage).

If I used that like

```
    @MyStorage('some-session-storage-value')
    public someValue: string = 'foobar';
```

I would understand, why the setter is called with `"foobar"` as `newValue` initially, but I don't get why it is always initialized with `undefined`. This did not happen with the experimental decorators and I can't see anything in the docs why this would have changed. I'm not sure if this is an Angular topic or a problem outside of the framework or a mix of both. When adding a `debugger();` in the setter I see, that the stack trace comes from the `SomeComponent`s constructor. Does anyone know why this happens or how I can solve the problem?
The only solution I currently see is something like (in the setter)

```
if(newValue === undefined) {
    // abort mission
    return;
}
```

But that would introduce the nasty problem of making a difference between `undefined` and `null` again, which I'd like not to do at all.